# Running rake migrate gives Mysql error schema_migrations.frm

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I am running 5.1 on Ubuntu 10.04, and the remote server is running 5.0.51, is this a problem?

Mysql::Error: Incorrect information in file: './user/schema_migrations.frm': SELECT version FROM schema_migrations

I should say that trying to install it gives the error of the package (mysql-server-5.0 referenced but not available). I believe it is available in 9.10, but how can I add those repos to 10.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrations table on the remote database was corrupt. I had to rebuild it.